# Passing arguments to Powershells Call Operatore - I can't get it to work

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

For some reason I cannot get even the most simple Ffmpeg case to work:

```
$pathToFfmpeg = "PathToFfmpeg\ffmpeg.exe"
$video = "PathToVideoFile\video.mp4"
$param = "--i $video", "output.avi"
$execute = &$pathToFfmpeg $param
```

This should result in the most basic Ffmpeg usage according to Ffmpeg website: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.avi`.
However all I receive is:

```
ffmpeg.exe : ffmpeg version git-2020-01-01-7b58702 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
At line:4 char:12
+ [string[]] $execute = &$pathToFfmpeg $param
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ffmpeg version ...mpeg developers:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20191125
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass 
--enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb 
--enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame 
--enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma 
--enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex 
--enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec 
--enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
  libavcodec     58. 65.100 / 58. 65.100
  libavformat    58. 35.101 / 58. 35.101
  libavdevice    58.  9.102 / 58.  9.102
  libavfilter     7. 70.101 /  7. 70.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Unrecognized option '-i PathToVideoFile\video.mp4'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

So it seems I am doing something wrong. Anybody knows how I get this to work? I have tried different methods to create the params array and checked with EchoArgs.exe, but no avail. I am out of ideas. It looks like Ffmpeg does not recognise what Powershell is passing to it.

Comment: Documentation says `-i`, you are using `--i`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried splatting?

Comment: @hcm: Yes that is a weird thing. Without double hyphen the error message is :
 
```Unrecognized option 'i PathToVideoFile\video.mp4'.```

Comment: @WalterMitty: Do you mean like this:
```$param = @("--i $video", "output.avi")
$execute = &$pathToFfmpeg @param```

This produces the same result. :(

Answer (score 0):

The call operator is sadly underdocumented.  This works for me if all the params are elements of an array, separated by commas.

```
$param = '-l','dns.ps1'
$prog = '/bin/ls'
& $prog $param

-rw-r--r--  1 jsz  staff  173 Dec 30 10:06 dns.ps1
```

But this seems to be the hard way of doing things.  Alternatively, specify the full path if there's no spaces (you can even backquote spaces), or add to the path first.  In Windows, use semicolon instead of colon.

```
/bin/ls -l dns.ps1

$env:PATH += ':/bin'
ls -l dns.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is solved. It seems that Ffmpeg is a bit picky how and which order it receives the arguments.
I wanna give credit to @IvBaranov and his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44902585/12637610) which gave the idea to add every part of a parameter on its own:

```
$param = @("--i", "$video", "output.avi")
```

Which seems to work.

Also credit goes to @Walter Mitty to try splatting again.

Comment: You can drop the `@( )`.